# ¿Cómo configurar los puertos de MariaDB Galera Cluster?

Tags: base-de-datos, mariadb, debian

Estoy configurando 2 nodos linux debian a través de internet de MariaDB Galera Cluster y no consigo que el servicio escuche en los puertos 3306 y 4567.

¿Me podéis echar un cable?

En el router está activo el DHCP, asignada una IP a una máquina virtual VMWARE, redirigidos los puertos 3306,4567,4568,4444 a ella.

En la máquina virtual tengo levantado el cluster con size=1.

He abierto los puertos con todo, iptables, firewall-cmd, ufw...

He probado con NAT y con Bridge en VMWARE pero nada...

Comment: Quizá es por que la ip se entrada es 127.0.0.1 en lugar de 0.0.0.0 que se muestra en iptables...

Comment: ¿Mapeaste los puertos de tu guest a tu host? Debes usar la dirección que asignó el host, no la interna del guest, no NAT, digo... con Bridge el guest tiene su propia IP dentro de la Intranet. Es un poquito complicado, solo tienes que hacer el planteamiento desde cero, porque si empiezas a mezclar conexiones se hace un relajo.

Comment: Los puertos están mapeados en el router y en vmware. Uso la IP que le he asignado en el DHCP del router, cuando tecleo ip a veo que tiene esa la interfaz.